# Resolve the recurrence for $T(n)=T(n-n/(\lg n))+ O(n\lg n)$

Tags: recurrence-relations

The recurrence I am looking for is the following.

$$T(n)=T\left(n-\frac{n}{\lg n}\right)+ O(n\lg n)$$

Does it solve to $O(n\lg^2 n)$?

Comment: My hunch is, you are right -- you have $\lg n$ terms in the expansion, and a noticeable portion of them are of size $O(n \lg n)$...

Comment: Can u give some rudimentary proof?
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this:
$$
\begin{split}
T(n)
  &\le T\left(n-\frac{n}{\lg n}\right)+ Kn\lg n \\
  &\le T\left(n-\frac{2n}{\lg n}\right)
     + Kn\lg n + K\left(\left(n-\frac{n}{\lg n}\right)\lg \left(n-\frac{n}{\lg n}\right)\right) \\
  &\le T\left(n-\frac{2n}{\lg n}\right) + 2Kn\lg n \\
  &\le \ldots \\
  &\le T(0) + (\lg n) K n \lg n \\
  &= O\left(n \lg^2 n \right)
\end{split}
$$

The only question is using the same $K$ in all inequalities with $n$ going down, but since the added term does not decrease here, it should be able to account for it...